# Use Pycharm only as a formatter

Tags: python, pycharm

I have used the regular IDLE python interpreter. Now I discovered PyCharm. It's a really good formatter and has a object hierarchy which I really like and auto-complete.

Unfortunately, PyCharm doesn't have the same interpreter as the regular python IDLE and I can't seem to get it to run w/ the regular python interpreter (Y'know, the one with the rocket in the icon?) and I can't seem to figure out how to get that same interpreter running

If you can give me any suggestions on how to get PyCharm to run on the regular interpreter, that would be nice, as I'm making a text based game, and the Pycharm console isn't great for those.

I've already tried looking into changing the pycharm interpreter (the rocketship python wasn't there) and the pycharm website didn't have exactly what i wanted

Basically, I want to only use PyCharm as a python formatter, and use the regular Python IDLE as a interpreter

Comment: Did you try clicking the little gear icon to the right of the 'Project Interpreter:' item in the `Project Interpreter` window?

Comment: You can configure by going into settings > project > interpreter, add from the dropdown where your interpreter is. check: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Comment: Can you give more details about the problem as I don't seem to understand it.

Comment: @JohnAnderson, yes I did, It didn't have the rocket ship icon python logo thing

Comment: @LakshyaSrivastava I looked into it before, it didnt have what i wanted

Comment: Maybe I’m not understanding what you want, but have you considered just using https://github.com/google/yapf or https://github.com/python/black?

Comment: Which specific python interpreter are you looking for @BrandonLi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting Interpreter in Pycharm can be done by going to:

- Settings -> Project -> Project interpreter
- In the project interpreter dropdown, you can find interpreters you used in different Pycharm projects(if any).
- If not then you can add them from the little + sign at the bottom go to the required new or existing environment and select the location of the base interpreter/ interpreter where you interpreter is saved in the file system.

[image: First]
[image: Second]
[image: Third]

Answer (score 0):

As John Anderson's comment said, You can configure python interpreter by File->Settings->Progject->Project Interpreter, you said it didn't have you wanted so you must add interpreter by hand. click the setting button, and Add a python interpreter.Generally python interpreter located in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python37\python.exe.

[image: pycharm interpreter]